# Internal Server error on post Request Using Made Custom Services in Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am new one for angular so i tried my best to solve this but after too much struggle i can't that's why asking. actually, i am not getting response back using `$http` i don't why because according to me it's seems right.

Two Questions For This Problem 
  1- Post Request Fail
  2- How CookieStore In angular

**signUpController.js**

```
app.controller('signUpController', function ($rootScope, $scope, signUpService, $location) {

    $scope.addUser = function(){


        var user = {
            "email": $scope.EmailInfo,
            "confirm_email": $scope.ConfirmEmailInfo,
            "password": $scope.PasswordInfo,
            "confirm_password": $scope.ConfirmPasswordInfo,
            "first_name": $scope.FirstnameInfo,
            "last_name": $scope.LastNameInfo,
            "dob": $scope.dateOfBirth,
            "gender": $scope.radioValue
        }

        signUpService.addNewUser(user).then(function(response) {

            if(response.status == 500) {
                $rootScope.loggedIn = false;
                $location.url('/SignUp');
            }else {
                $rootScope.loggedIn = true;
                $location.url('/Stores');
                console.log(data);
            }
            console.log(response);

        });

    }
});
```

**signUpService.js**

```
app.factory('signUpService', function($http, $cookieStore) {

    var signUpServices = {

        addNewUser : function(user) {

            var promise = $http({
                method:'POST',
                url: "/user/register?account_id=" + utils.urlParam('account_id') ,
                data: user
            }).then(function(response) {

                    $cookieStore.put("token", response["token"]); // is it write that i used also check please
                    console.log(response.data);
                    return response.data;
                },
                    function(reason) {
                        alert("There was a problem");
                    });

            return promise;
        }
    };
    return signUpServices;
});
```

**error**

```
POST http://localhost:3000/user/register?account_id=0 500 (Internal Server Error) angular.js:10159
(anonymous function) angular.js:10159
sendReq angular.js:9980
$http.serverRequest angular.js:9757
deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback angular.js:7303
deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback angular.js:7303
(anonymous function) angular.js:7340
Scope.$eval angular.js:8685
Scope.$digest angular.js:8548
Scope.$apply angular.js:8771
(anonymous function) angular.js:13970
f.event.dispatch jquery.js:3
h.handle.i
```

**Updated** But Same Issue

```
app.factory('signUpService', function($http) {

    var signUpServices = {
        addNewUser : function(user) {

            var promise = $http({method: 'POST', url: "/user/register?account_id=" + utils.urlParam('account_id'),
                data: user}).

                success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log("response");
                    alert(data);
                }).

                error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    alert(status);
                });

            return promise;
        }
    };
    return signUpServices;
});
```

i will be really grateful to you if someone rectify this where need to required changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using $http wrong

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: '/someUrl'}).
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }). 
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

Here is how you can get cookie on each request:

```
        $http.defaults.transformRequest.push(function (data) {
            data.csrfToken = $browser.cookies().csrfToken;
            return angular.toJson(data);
        });
```

Comment: Status 500 mean that some error in server side. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes Check your backend code